# How do I calculate the unit vector of P = (3, 4, 5) and Q = (5, 8, 9) (line l going through these two points)?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

My textbook says that the answer to this question is: unit vector v = (Q − P) / |Q −P| = (1/3) [1 2 2]. I don't see how they got here, this is my calculation: (Q - P) = [5 - 3, 8 - 4, 9 - 5] = [2 4 4]. The magnitude of this vector is the square root of (2*2)+(4*4)+(4*4) = 36 so 6. So I'd say that the unit vector is 1/6 [2 4 4].

Comment: These two are equivalent. [2 4 4] = 2[ 1 2 2]

Comment: @user399625 Ah thank you, it's just the whole piece divided by two?

Comment: For a scalar multiple $c$ and an arbitrary vector $v$, $\vec{cv}=c\vec{v}$

Comment: Yes correct. So both forms are correct but they have just taken out the factor of 2 from all the terms to make it simpler.$\frac{[1,2,2]}{3}$ = $[\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3}]$ 
 and $\frac{[2,4,4]}{6}$ = $[\frac{2}{6},\frac{4}{6},\frac{4}{6}]$ = $[\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3}]$